# What is the relationship between DirectAccess, Web Application Proxy, and Forefront UAG?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access, microsoft-forefront, direct-access

We're exploring the feasibility of deploying DirectAccess to our off-campus laptops as a more seamless alternative to our TS-Gateway server, and I would like to know the benefits and relationship between these similar technologies.

DirectAccess and Web Application Proxy are roles you can install on Server 2012, but UAG is a fully licensed product.  I understand what DirectAccess and Web Application Proxy do, but what does Forefront UAG bring to the table?  How do these products overlap with each other?  What are the differences between them?  In what scenarios would I use one over the other?

As is typical for Microsoft, their web site just offers a lot of marketing speak that doesn't really explain things in detail.  And the Wikipedia page for UAG just reiterates what I already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forefront UAG is discontinued.  Essentially the other technologies you mention supersede the UAG functionality.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/server-cloud/archive/2013/12/17/important-changes-to-the-forefront-product-line.aspx